# SSMS How to Click within Query to Open Table

Tags: ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

I come from oracle SQL Developer world where I can ctrl+click on a table name within a query and the table definition automatically opens.  This is great as it alleviates my need to navigate within the Tree and drill down until I find the table I'm looking for.

How do I do this in SSMS?  I have looked online however I have not found any answers that show this is even a possibility.

A quick search for Oracle comes up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935322/oracle-sql-developer-how-to-open-table-view-by-clicking-double-clicking-on-its).

But again since I no longer work with Oracle how do I do this same thing in SSMS?

Comment: I'm not sure that functionality is built into SSMS, but you can do what you want with the free version of [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com/VersionCompare).  See _Locate Object_ - Quickly find object located at cursor position in object explorer. Shortcut: Ctrl-F2

Comment: @ScottHodgin I was afraid of that... the switch to SSMS has been a bit disappointing.  I'm installing all of these plugins/extensions for things that should just be built in lol.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you highlight the table name in SSMS and hit Alt-F1, you'll get some information about the table that may answer your question - see [Shortcut Key for Table Details in Sql Server Management Studio](https://www.developertipoftheday.com/2010/07/shortcut-key-for-table-details-in-sql.html)

Comment: @ScottHodgin I'm using both options.  Installed SSMSBoost and I'm using the Alt+F1 for the table info in the Results pane.  Very nice!